# Rspec for complicated case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to RSpec, and struggling with how to test with mock.
This is basically called when webhook comes in.

```
class InvoiceCreated
  def call(event)
    invoice = event.data.object

    # NOTE: Skip if the invoice is closed.
    if invoice.closed == false
      stripe_customer = invoice.customer
      payment_account = PaymentCardAccount.find_by(stripe_customer_id: stripe_customer)
      card_invoice = Invoice.find_card_invoice_in_this_month_within(payment_account: payment_account)

      card_invoice.process_invoice_items(stripe_customer: stripe_customer,
                                         event_invoice_id: invoice.id)
      card_invoice.process!(:pending, id: invoice.id)
    end
  end
end
```

I'd love to use mock and prevent API calling for testing for two lines of code below.

```
 card_invoice.process_invoice_items(stripe_customer: stripe_customer,
                                     event_invoice_id: invoice.id)

  card_invoice.process!(:pending, id: invoice.id)
```

how can I use mock for those?

Comment: Which version of rspec are you using?

Comment: I use 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4.2'.

Comment: When you say "mock", what are you actually trying to achieve here? Do you just want a dummy object that won't actually do anything, and won't fail with an error like `NoMethodError: Undefined method process_invoice_items`? Or, do you actually want to stub out a web API call that processes the invoice, but otherwise perform a "full test" of this functionality? What is this test trying to achieve? (Perhaps you could include the current test, in the post above?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expect_any_instance_of` to check that you call `Invoice#process_invoice_items` and `Invoice#process` with the correct parameters. If you do not care about how they are called you can just stub them and use `allow_any_instance_of` for this.

```
expect_any_instance_of(Invoice).to receive(:process_invoice_items)
expect_any_instance_of(Invoice).to receive(:process!)
```

[See here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) for more detailed examples and got through the basic section of `rspec-mock` to see what you can do with it actually.